# Undefined variable: value in PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to print the value of a variable from a function, but it is showing undefined variable value. Please help me and tell me how to solve this problem; I'm pretty new
to `PHP` coding. I tried the function as public, but it shows some other error.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
    {
        $num1 = $_POST['cards1'];
        $num2 = $_POST['cards2'];
        $num1=substr($num1,0,(strlen($num1)-1));
        $num2=substr($num2,0,(strlen($num2)-1));
    }

    function get_value() {

        switch ($num2) {

            case 'A' :
                $value = 11;
                break;
            case 'J':
            case 'Q':
            case 'K':
                $value = 10;
                break;
            default:
                $value = $num2;
                break;

        }

            //return $value;
    }   
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Out Put is'.$value.' ");</script>';

        //$total_value =  $num1+$num2;      


  ?>
```

Comment: Here `$value` is local to the function. Make it global and you can use then

Comment: `function get_value($num2) {`

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: @prava You should avoid using the `global` keyword. There's almost always a much better way to do it. My comment above being a great example.

Comment: and here OP has to return the value also :) and then can use it :)

Answer (score 0):

`$num2` is local to your function. You need to pass it in as a parameter:

```
function get_value($num2) {

*** YOUR CODE

}
```

Comment: still showing undefined variable error for value

Comment: did you pass in $num2 into the function?

Comment: yes i did  function get_value($num2) {
 
  switch ($num2) {
  
   case 'A' :
    $value = 11;
    break;
   case 'J':
   case 'Q':
   case 'K':
    $value = 10;
    break;
   default:
    $value = $num2;
    break;
    
  }
   
   //return $value;
  }

Comment: remove comment from here - `//return $value;` You should return the value and then use it here `echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Out Put is'. get_value($num2) .' ");</script>';`